# Getting C1001 Internal compiler error when building pytorch on windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, torch, libtorch

I'm trying to build Pytorch on windows using visual studio, but it seems it faces some internal compiler error which I have not been able to figure out its cause.
out of 46 targets, 35 gets built successfully until it ultimately fails with the following errors.
Before I list the errors this is how I went about building it :

```
git clone --branch v1.6.0 https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git pytorch-1.6.0
cd pytorch-1.6.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
set CUDAHOSTCXX=
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -version [15^,16^) -products * -latest -property installationPath`) do call "%i\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 -vcvars_ver=14.27
python setup.py build --cmake-only
cmake-gui
```

and this is what I did afterward:
[image: pytorch_build|690x323]

build outout:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: defs.bzl, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: ATEN_CPU_FILES_GEN_TARGET, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: dnnl_cpu, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: generate-torch-sources, Configuration: Release x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: python_copy_files, Configuration: Release x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: gen_onnx_proto, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>Generating ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/variable_factories.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_variable_methods.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_torch_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_nn_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.h
7>------ Build started: Project: __aten_op_header_gen, Configuration: Release x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: torch_python_stubs, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>cpu_concat.cpp
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>cpu_layer_normalization_list.cpp
3>cpu_shuffle_list.cpp
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>gemm_convolution_utils.cpp
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>ref_convolution.cpp
3>ref_deconvolution.cpp
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>ref_eltwise.cpp
3>cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W1' with '/w'
3>ref_inner_product.cpp
3>ref_layer_normalization.cpp
3>ref_lrn.cpp
3>ref_pooling.cpp
3>ref_resampling.cpp
3>ref_shuffle.cpp
3>ref_softmax.cpp
3>D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\gemm_convolution_utils.cpp(401): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
3>(compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\7\s\src\vctools\Compiler\Utc\src\p2\main.c', line 195)
3> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
3>If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
3>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
3> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
3>  CL!RaiseException()+0x69
3>  CL!RaiseException()+0x69
3>  CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0x22e6b
3>  CL!CloseTypeServerPDB()+0xcd30a
3>simple_concat.cpp
3>simple_layer_normalization.cpp
3>simple_layer_normalization_kernels.cpp
3>simple_resampling.cpp
3>simple_sum.cpp
3>gemm_utils_f32.cpp
3>ref_gemm_f32.cpp
3>gemm.cpp
3>gemm_pack.cpp
3>ref_gemm_s8x8s32.cpp
3>simple_gemm_s8s8s32.cpp
3>cpu_matmul_list.cpp
3>cl : command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process
3>Done building project "dnnl_cpu.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
9>------ Build started: Project: dnnl, Configuration: Release x64 ------
9>Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.27.29111.0
9>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
9>
9>"/OUT:D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\lib\Release\dnnl.lib" /NOLOGO /MACHINE:X64 /machine:x64 /ignore:4049 /ignore:4217 dnnl.dir\Release\version.res
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\batch_normalization.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\binary.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\concat.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\convolution.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\convolution_pd.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\deconvolution.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\dnnl_debug.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\dnnl_debug_autogenerated.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\eltwise.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\engine.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\inner_product.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\layer_normalization.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\lrn.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\matmul.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\memory.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\memory_debug.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\memory_desc_wrapper.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\memory_storage.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\memory_zero_pad.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\pooling.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_attr.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_cache.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_desc.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_exec_types.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_hashing.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\primitive_iterator.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\query.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\reorder.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\resampling.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\rnn.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\rw_mutex.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\scratchpad.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\scratchpad_debug.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\shuffle.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\softmax.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\stream.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\stream_attr.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\sum.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\utils.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\common\dnnl_common.dir\Release\verbose.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\bfloat16.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_batch_normalization_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_batch_normalization_utils.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_binary_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_concat.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_convolution_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_deconvolution_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_eltwise_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_engine.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_inner_product_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_layer_normalization_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_lrn_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_pooling_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_reorder.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_resampling_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_rnn_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_shuffle_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_softmax_list.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\cpu_sum.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\gemm_convolution.obj"
9>"D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\gemm_convolution_utils.obj"
9>D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\gemm_convolution_utils.obj : fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file
9>Done building project "dnnl.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
10>------ Build started: Project: torch_cpu, Configuration: Release x64 ------
11>------ Build started: Project: compat_libs, Configuration: Release x64 ------
11>Error copying file "D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/lib/Release/dnnl.lib" to "D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/lib/Release/mkldnn.lib".
11>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(234,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
11>Done building project "compat_libs.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
10>Generating ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/jit/generated/generated_unboxing_wrappers_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ProfiledType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/variable_factories.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_variable_methods.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_torch_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_nn_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_functions.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_functions.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_variable_methods.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_torch_functions.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_nn_functions.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_0.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_0.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_0.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_1.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_1.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_1.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_2.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_2.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_2.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_3.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_3.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_3.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_4.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_4.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_4.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableTypeEverything.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledTypeEverything.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceTypeEverything.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\RegistrationDeclarations.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\Functions.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\Functions.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\variable_factories.h
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_0.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_1.cpp
4>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_2.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_functions.h
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_functions.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_variable_methods.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_torch_functions.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\python_nn_functions.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType.h
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_0.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_0.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_0.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_1.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_1.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_1.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_2.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_2.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_2.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_3.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_3.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_3.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableType_4.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledType_4.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceType_4.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\VariableTypeEverything.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\ProfiledTypeEverything.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\TraceTypeEverything.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\RegistrationDeclarations.h
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\Functions.h
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\Functions.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\autograd\generated\variable_factories.h
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_0.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_1.cpp
10>Skipped writing torch/csrc\jit\generated\generated_unboxing_wrappers_2.cpp
10>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\dnnl.lib'
10>Done building project "torch_cpu.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
12>------ Build started: Project: torch, Configuration: Release x64 ------
12>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\torch_cpu.lib'
12>Done building project "torch.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
13>------ Build started: Project: caffe2_pybind11_state, Configuration: Release x64 ------
14>------ Build started: Project: shm, Configuration: Release x64 ------
15>------ Build started: Project: caffe2_observers, Configuration: Release x64 ------
16>------ Build started: Project: caffe2_detectron_ops, Configuration: Release x64 ------
15>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'
15>Done building project "caffe2_observers.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
14>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'
14>Done building project "shm.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
17>------ Build started: Project: torch_python, Configuration: Release x64 ------
18>------ Build started: Project: windows_python_copy_lib, Configuration: Release x64 ------
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'
16>Done building project "caffe2_detectron_ops.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
18>Error copying file "D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python/Release/caffe2_pybind11_state.cp37-win_amd64.pyd" to "D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python".
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python/Release/caffe2_pybind11_state.cp37-win_amd64.pyd D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
18>Done building project "windows_python_copy_lib.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
17>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\shm.lib'
17>Done building project "torch_python.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 7 succeeded, 11 failed, 28 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Linker errrors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1001   Internal compiler error.    dnnl_cpu    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\gemm_convolution_utils.cpp 401 
Error   D8040   error creating or communicating with child process  dnnl_cpu    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\cl   1   
Error   LNK1136 invalid or corrupt file dnnl    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\src\cpu\dnnl_cpu.dir\Release\gemm_convolution_utils.obj  1   
Error   MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.   compat_libs C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets    234 
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\dnnl.lib'    torch_cpu   D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\caffe2\LINK    1   
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\torch_cpu.lib'   torch   D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\caffe2\LINK    1   
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'    caffe2_observers    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\modules\observers\LINK 1   
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'  shm D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\caffe2\torch\lib\libshm_windows\LINK   1   
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\torch.lib'    caffe2_detectron_ops    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\modules\detectron\LINK 1   
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python/Release/caffe2_pybind11_state.cp37-win_amd64.pyd D:/Codes/pytorch-1.6.0/build_dir/caffe2/python
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. windows_python_copy_lib C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets    149 
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\shm.lib'  torch_python    D:\Codes\pytorch-1.6.0\build_dir\caffe2\torch\LINK  1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe your options are 1. Complain to Microsoft about their bug, 2. Try a different version of the msvc compiler, or 3. Try what the error message suggests: ***To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above***

Comment: @drescherjm thanks a lot. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I do understand #3 is a very difficult task when you are not the writer of the software. You may also want to file a bug report on the github page. Maybe the authors of the software have a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not [the first to encounter this issue](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDNN/issues/812):

> Moving from Visual Studio v16.6.4 to v16.7.1, we now see the following
> error when compiling oneDNN:
>
> [path]src\cpu\gemm_convolution_utils.cpp(401) : fatal error C1001:
> Internal compiler error.

A fix for your issue is [included in Pytorch 1.6.2](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDNN/issues/812#issuecomment-687244794).

The compiler bug itself is still [under investigation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1145942/vs2019-internal-compiler-error-using-restrict-keyw.html) and has not been solved as of today.

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate it. Updating to 16.7.5 didnt do any good either as you also pointed out. just wanted to add this here as well that its not limited to 16.7.1

Comment: Also it seems the change is a one liner .i.e just change `auto zero_val = (data_t)0;` to `const data_t zero_val = 0;` in `src/cpu/gemm_convolution_utils.cpp` and thats all. [ref](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDNN/commit/c6f9b7a3e5833bfe06580be6c70c7a4e019e3a43)

Answer (score 3):

An *Internal compiler error* is always a bug with the compiler. In this case, it's prevented building of a library that is needed later in the build process.

Your options are limited. I suggest trying a different version of Visual Studio.

You should also report this to Microsoft.